# Error handling for View State of vf page in Apex Salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, error-messages, viewstate

I have one vf page in which I have a requirement to display huge data but as we know Vf page has View state Limit as 135 KB , hence after reaching this Limit salesforce throws Exception as "Maximum view state size limit (135KB) exceeded". 
So I have to show a custom  Message on VF page when this limit is exceeded.
Is there any way to check this limit in code? or way to throw a custom message after limit is exceeded.
Thnaks In Advance.

Comment: You typically know the list size when your page explodes.So check size of the list and populate message and clear the list to avoid view state error .

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at following article:

[Introduction to Visualforce View State](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce_View_State)

The use of `transient` keyword will allow you to minimize the Viewstate. Though, technically there is no known way to calculate Viewstate in visualforce via Salesforce Apex API, we just need to code within the best practices boundaries and that usually make sure that Viewstate issues never arise, also as @Mohith mentioned, clearing of Variables/List variables or variables specifically of `blob` datatype (file upload controls), also minimizes Viewstate by a good margin.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the answer I posted to [best-practices-for-custom-controller-actions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60691/best-practices-for-custom-controller-actions/60702#60702) which includes a summary of view state and what impacts it most when optimizing custom controllers. In particular there's a reference to an excellent webinar on [Advanced Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/events/webinars/advanced_visualforce_salesforce1?d=70130000000i3sO) by @PBattison that should be available for viewing any day now.