# How to catch View State Exception and display custom message instead

Tags: visualforce, javascript, viewstate

I have a controller extension for a VF page that runs a query that could possibly over load the view state, I don't want to optimize it but instead catch the exception and display a custom message. Is this possible ? If not, on the VF page, can I not detect that the view state size limit has been surpassed 'onLoad' or something similar ? Maybe with javascript ?

Comment: Have you looked into this?https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/61410/error-handling-for-view-state-of-vf-page-in-apex-salesforce

Comment: Yes, thank you, I'm not looking to optimize. I can't seem to find anyway to check the view state size when the page loads. Some where in salesforce that view state exception limit message is saved and I want to display something of my own

Comment: I don't think there is a way to calculate view state! One other way would be if you are displaying a list of records, like mohit was speaking in the other thread you could look for other limits(like 10k rows) and do some custom error handling

Comment: If your use case is very specific it will be easy for community members to suggest you a more precise solution!

Comment: Most governor limits exceptions can't be caught or handled. In some cases you can instrument to check if you're getting close by looking at (e.g.) how many SOQL queries have been executed in the current transaction, but that doesn't really apply in the same way to view state.

Comment: Well that's inconvenient